# Connection between MySQL workbench Database and java using Intellij

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am a beginner in java coding and was stuck on a problem that I had been receiving while trying to get the text that I put inside of my Jtextfield to save inside of my MySQL database,

This is my current code, it runs fine but inserts a blank row into my database when I try to save my text

This is my main class:

```
public class Main{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MyFrame();
}
}
```

This is my class for my main menu:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;



public class MyFrame extends JFrame{



JLabel label;
JMenu Add;
JMenu remove;
JMenu items;
JMenu vendors;
JMenuBar menuBar;
JMenuItem addCustomer;
JMenuItem addVendors;
JMenuItem addProducts;
JMenuItem removeCustomer;
JMenuItem removeProduct;
JMenuItem removeVendor;



MyFrame(){
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    label = new JLabel("Inventory Software");
    label.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 30));

    menuBar = new JMenuBar();

    Add = new JMenu("Add");
    remove = new JMenu("Remove");
    items = new JMenu("Items");
    vendors = new JMenu("Vendors");


    addCustomer = new JMenuItem("Add Customers");
    addVendors = new JMenuItem("Add Vendors");
    addProducts = new JMenuItem("Add Products");

    removeCustomer = new JMenuItem("Remove Customer");
    removeProduct = new JMenuItem("Remove Product");
    removeVendor = new JMenuItem("Remove Vendor");


    remove.add(removeCustomer);
    remove.add(removeProduct);
    remove.add(removeVendor);

    Add.add(addCustomer);
    Add.add(addProducts);
    Add.add(addVendors);

    menuBar.add(Add);
    menuBar.add(remove);
    menuBar.add(items);
    menuBar.add(vendors);


    addCustomer.addActionListener(new WindowAC());
    addVendors.addActionListener(new WindowAV());
    addProducts.addActionListener(new WindowAP());
    removeCustomer.addActionListener(new WindowRC());
    removeVendor.addActionListener(new WindowRV());
    removeProduct.addActionListener(new WindowRP());


    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(550, 300));
    this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    this.add(label);
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setTitle("Intact Communications Inventory Software");
    }
    }
```

This is my class for my Add customer tab containing the Jtextfield:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class WindowAC implements ActionListener
{

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if("Add Customers".equals(e.getActionCommand())){

        JFrame windowAC = new JFrame();

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Name:");
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Address:");
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Email:");
        JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Tel: ");
        JLabel label4 = new JLabel("FAX: ");
        JLabel label5 = new JLabel(" ");

        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        JTextField textField1 = new JTextField();
        JTextField textField2 = new JTextField();
        JTextField textField3 = new JTextField();
        JTextField textField4 = new JTextField();

        JButton button = new JButton("Submit");

        String s1, s2;

        label.setBounds(50, 100, 100, 50);
        label1.setBounds(50, 150, 100, 50);
        label2.setBounds(50, 200, 100, 50);
        label3.setBounds(50, 250, 100, 50);
        label4.setBounds(50, 300, 100, 50);
        label5.setBounds(50, 350, 100, 50);



        textField.setBounds(150, 110, 400, 30);
        textField1.setBounds(150, 160, 400, 30);
        textField2.setBounds(150, 210, 400, 30);
        textField3.setBounds(150, 260, 400, 30);
        textField4.setBounds(150, 310, 400, 30);

        button.setBounds(300, 450, 100, 70);

        windowAC.add(button);
        windowAC.add(label);
        windowAC.add(textField);
        windowAC.add(label1);
        windowAC.add(textField1);
        windowAC.add(label2);
        windowAC.add(textField2);
        windowAC.add(label3);
        windowAC.add(textField3);
        windowAC.add(label4);
        windowAC.add(textField4);
        windowAC.add(label5);

        windowAC.setSize(750,750);
        windowAC.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        windowAC.setTitle("Add Customer info");
        windowAC.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        windowAC.setVisible(true);
        windowAC.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        s1 = textField.getText();
        s2 = textField1.getText();

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                System.out.println(e1);
            }
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/inventoryapp", "root", "P@kist@n1");
            System.out.println("Connection is created successfully:");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String query1 = "INSERT INTO names(first_name,last_name) VALUES ('" + s1 + "','" + s2 + "')";
            stmt.executeUpdate(query1);
            System.out.println("Record is inserted in the table successfully..................");
        } catch (SQLException excep) {
            excep.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception excep) {
            excep.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (stmt != null)
                    conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {}
            try {
                if (conn != null)
                    conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Please check it in the MySQL Table...........");

        }
    }

}
```

My code tells me that the data from the Jtextfield has saved fine inside if my datatbase but my database only inserts a blank row instead of what I typed into my textfield

Comment: You execute the insert at the same time that you display the form, when you need to do it on an ActionListener attached to the submit button, that is when the user has had a chance to enter some data. Also, research prepared statements and try-with-resources.

Comment: I was wondering if you could please share some code as to how to do that because I am having some difficulty doing so, Thanks.